# Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'FirestoreModule'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following problem.
I have installed AngularFire via npm i @angular/fire in latest version and have also set up Firestore. Now I want to load data into my Firestore but I get the error message "Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'FirestoreModule'."

```
//AppModule.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environments.prod';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { FirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './layouts/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './layouts/footer/footer.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { CategoriesComponent } from './categories/categories.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    CategoriesComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    FirestoreModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}




//Component

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.scss'],
})
export class CategoriesComponent {
  constructor(private afs: FirestoreModule) {}

  onSubmit(formData: any) {
    const categoryData = {
      category: formData.value.category,
    };

    this.afs.collection('category').add(categoryData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire):

```
import { Firestore, collectionData, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export class AppComponent {
  item$: Observable<Item[]>;
  firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);

  constructor() {
    const itemCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'items');
    this.item$ = collectionData(itemCollection);
  }
}
```